# Passing Javascript Variable to PHP using Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I wanna pass a JavaScript variable in to php using Ajax... coz I wanna pass it onclick. I'm getting the onclick value to variable row. Help would b gratefull :) Thank You

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateTable(row) {
    alert (row);
    var row = (row);
}

</script>
```

Comment: see w3schools ajax php

Comment: refer this link to [ajax call from javascript to php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804327/jquery-ajax-call-from-javascript-to-php)

Answer (score 0):

Did u try this?

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'do.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: "userID=" + onlyID,
    success: onMemberSucces,
    error:onMemberError
  });

function onMemberSucces(data) {
alert(data);
}

function onMemberError() {
alert("Error!!");
}
```

where do.php is your php file and onlyID is your javascript variable.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: thanx for the reply.. First of all it's on the same page.sorry I culdn't mention that. Yeah i tried this one and some other but nothing happen... Thank you

Comment: what do u mean "it's on the same page?"

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461786/pass-javascript-variable-to-php-via-ajax

Comment: i hope that's what u r looking for?