# Pass a string from ajax to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm simply trying to read in a field from a text box, pass the value via ajax to PHP and then store the data in a mysql table. The table is already set up and ready to go, all I need is to insert values.

Here is my js file

```
    var address = $("input#email").val(); 
    //If submission is valid 
    if(submitForm == "true"){
        $.ajax({  
            url: "bin/process.php",  
            type: "POST",  
            data: {email: address},   
            success: function(response) {  
            $('#message').html(response); 
            }
        });  
        return false; 
    }
```

And then my PHP looks like this

```
    <?php

       function process($email){

        //Connect to the database  
        $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') ; 
        if(!$con){ 
          retun mysql_error();  
        }

        //Insert Data into the Table
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO Users(email) VALUES ('$email')' ; 
        $query = mysql_query($sql, $con) 
        if(!$query){
          return mysql_error();
        }

        return "Thank you for your submission!"; 
       }

       echo process(trim($_POST['email']));
     ?>
```

Right now I am getting this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING /opt/lampp/htdocs/mysite/bin/process.php on line 3
```

So it appears that I am not passing the address value correctly, but I cannot figure out why.  For reference I was following the instructions on this post: [Jquery ajax call from javascript to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804327/jquery-ajax-call-from-javascript-to-php)

I don't quite understand the last echo line, but I tried multiple methods, and they all gave me the same error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: string concatenation uses `.` ie  `echo 'var is:'.$var;`

Answer (score 3):

You spelled function wrong: `funtion process($email){`

It should be `function process($email){`

Any decent text editor or IDE would catch that instantly for you.

Comment: I don't think it is correct. =

Comment: Why do you not think so?

Comment: check the question function is written properly i don't see mistyped as funtion

Comment: That's because they editted it after I posted my answer

Comment: It matches the error message they have. Really this question should just be closed as too localized and a disaster.

Comment: and its on line 3 as per error reporting (ditto LOL)

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, as soon as I posted it, the syntax highlighting on the sight pointed out that error, and I corrected it. I still am unable to complete the task at hand.

Comment: @Dan there are 3 more errors check my answer, it will help you

Answer (score 3):

I found 3 errors in your code

1. `retun mysql_error(); // return spelling wrong`
2. `$sql = 'INSERT INTO Users(email) VALUES ('$email')' ; // syntax error`
3. `$query = mysql_query($sql, $con); // semicolon missing`

corrected code is...

```
<?php
       function process($email){

        //Connect to the database  
        $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') ; 
        if(!$con){ 
          return mysql_error();  
        }

        //Insert Data into the Table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Users(email) VALUES ('$email')" ; 
        $query = mysql_query($sql, $con);
        if(!$query){
          return mysql_error();
        }

        return "Thank you for your submission!"; 
       }

       echo process(trim($_POST['email']));
     ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. TIL I need a better text editor.

Comment: your welcome :) and you can use Dreamweaver OR notepad++

Answer (score 1):

Change your query from single qoutes to this

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO Users(email) VALUES ('$email')" ;
```

Because single quotes won't parse the variables.