# Why this jQuery clock doesn't work properly to display the server-side time?

Tags: jquery, server-side, clock

I'd like to ask you guys why this jQuery clock it's working properly to display the server time but instead it displays the time on the PC when you browse the website (and I want to display only the server side time from machine).

`jQuery1`

```
         $(function($) {
          var pstOptions = {
            timeNotation: '12h',
            am_pm: true,
            utc: true,
            utc_offset: <%SETTING_TIMEOFFSET%>,
            fontFamily: 'Verdana, Times New Roman',
            fontSize: '11px',
            foreground: 'white',

            background: 'black'
          }
          $('.jclockPST').jclock(pstOptions);
        });
```

`jQuery2`

```
 /*
 * jQuery jclock - Clock plugin - v 0.2.1
 * http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jclock
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2007-2008 Doug Sparling <http://www.dougsparling.com>
 * Licensed under the MIT License:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */
(function($) {

  $.fn.jclock = function(options) {
    var version = '0.2.1';

    // options
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.jclock.defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      $this.timerID = null;
      $this.running = false;

      var o = $.meta ? $.extend({}, opts, $this.data()) : opts;

      $this.timeNotation = o.timeNotation;
      $this.am_pm = o.am_pm;
      $this.utc = o.utc;
      $this.utc_offset = o.utc_offset;

      $this.css({
        fontFamily: o.fontFamily,
        fontSize: o.fontSize,
        backgroundColor: o.background,
        color: o.foreground
      });

      $.fn.jclock.startClock($this);

    });
  };

  $.fn.jclock.startClock = function(el) {
    $.fn.jclock.stopClock(el);
    $.fn.jclock.displayTime(el);
  }
  $.fn.jclock.stopClock = function(el) {
    if(el.running) {
      clearTimeout(el.timerID);
    }
    el.running = false;
  }
  $.fn.jclock.displayTime = function(el) {
    var time = $.fn.jclock.getTime(el);
    el.html(time);
    el.timerID = setTimeout(function(){$.fn.jclock.displayTime(el)},1000);
  }
  $.fn.jclock.getTime = function(el) {
    var now = new Date();
    var hours, minutes, seconds;

    if(el.utc == true) {
      if(el.utc_offset != 0) {
        now.setUTCHours(now.getUTCHours()+el.utc_offset);
      }
      hours = now.getUTCHours();
      minutes = now.getUTCMinutes();
      seconds = now.getUTCSeconds();
    } else {
      hours = now.getHours();
      minutes = now.getMinutes();
      seconds = now.getSeconds();
    }

    var am_pm_text = '';
    (hours >= 12) ? am_pm_text = " P.M." : am_pm_text = " A.M.";

    if (el.timeNotation == '12h') {
      hours = ((hours > 12) ? hours - 12 : hours);
    } else {
      hours   = ((hours <  10) ? "0" : "") + hours;
    }

    minutes = ((minutes <  10) ? "0" : "") + minutes;
    seconds = ((seconds <  10) ? "0" : "") + seconds;

    var timeNow = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if ( (el.timeNotation == '12h') && (el.am_pm == true) ) {
     timeNow += am_pm_text;
    }

    return timeNow;
  };

  // plugin defaults
  $.fn.jclock.defaults = {
    timeNotation: '24h',
    am_pm: false,
    utc: false,
    fontFamily: '',
    fontSize: '',
    foreground: '',
    background: '',
    utc_offset: 0
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: That section you marked as "PHP" looks like jQuery to me.

Comment: Sorry, It's jQuery. I typed it by mistake. There's no php.

Comment: So where do you make a call to your server to get your server's time? How is the client supposed to know the server's time?

Comment: I'm displaying this clock on my website, so when someone browse it .. it should grab the time on the machine where the website is hosted and NOT the time from user that is browsing it.

Comment: Then you need to call a script on your server that sends the time back to the client. I think the problem here is that you have no concept of server and client.

Comment: Alright. I've got another idea ... how to make it so that the time offset will work correctly instead of getting the time from server side machine ? Now when I set time offeset to +3 for example it displays the time from the user that is browsing thr website. so there still must be a way to display the clock for time zone +3 gmt for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script never contacts your server at any time. You are going to need a server side script that outputs the time.

Create a PHP file named `GetTime.php` and place it on your server. It should have the following contents:

**PHP**

```
<?php
echo time();
```

Next, you need to modify your script to get the time from your server script.

You don't want to continuously do this because it could cause delays in updating your clock. So, do it on clock initialization, and store an offset between the server and the client. Then apply that offset each time the client date is retrieved in the `getTime()` function.

**jQuery**

```
 /*
 * jQuery jclock - Clock plugin - v 0.2.1
 * http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jclock
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2007-2008 Doug Sparling <http://www.dougsparling.com>
 * Licensed under the MIT License:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */
(function($) {

  $.fn.jclock = function(options) {
    var version = '0.2.1';

    // options
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.jclock.defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      $this.timerID = null;
      $this.running = false;

      $.fn.jclock.getServerOffset($this);

      var o = $.meta ? $.extend({}, opts, $this.data()) : opts;

      $this.timeNotation = o.timeNotation;
      $this.am_pm = o.am_pm;
      $this.utc = o.utc;
      $this.utc_offset = o.utc_offset;

      $this.css({
        fontFamily: o.fontFamily,
        fontSize: o.fontSize,
        backgroundColor: o.background,
        color: o.foreground
      });

      $.fn.jclock.startClock($this);

    });
  };

  $.fn.jclock.getServerOffset = function(el) {
    //Want to make a synchronous call to the server to get the server time.
    $.ajax({
        url: "GetTime.php",
        async: false,
        context: el,
        success: function(result) {
            var serverDate = new Date(+(result) * 1000); //Convert the seconds to a number, and multiple by 1000 to get milliseconds.
            var clientDate = new Date();

            $this.serverOffset = clientDate - serverDate; //Set the offset between server and client.
        }
    });
  };

  $.fn.jclock.startClock = function(el) {
    $.fn.jclock.stopClock(el);
    $.fn.jclock.displayTime(el);
  };

  $.fn.jclock.stopClock = function(el) {
    if(el.running) {
      clearTimeout(el.timerID);
    }
    el.running = false;
  };

  $.fn.jclock.displayTime = function(el) {
    var time = $.fn.jclock.getTime(el);
    el.html(time);
    el.timerID = setTimeout(function(){$.fn.jclock.displayTime(el)},1000);
  };

  $.fn.jclock.getTime = function(el) {
    var now = new Date(new Date().getTime() - el.serverOffset); //Apply the server offset.
    var hours, minutes, seconds;

    if(el.utc == true) {
      if(el.utc_offset != 0) {
        now.setUTCHours(now.getUTCHours()+el.utc_offset);
      }
      hours = now.getUTCHours();
      minutes = now.getUTCMinutes();
      seconds = now.getUTCSeconds();
    } else {
      hours = now.getHours();
      minutes = now.getMinutes();
      seconds = now.getSeconds();
    }

    var am_pm_text = '';
    (hours >= 12) ? am_pm_text = " P.M." : am_pm_text = " A.M.";

    if (el.timeNotation == '12h') {
      hours = ((hours > 12) ? hours - 12 : hours);
    } else {
      hours   = ((hours <  10) ? "0" : "") + hours;
    }

    minutes = ((minutes <  10) ? "0" : "") + minutes;
    seconds = ((seconds <  10) ? "0" : "") + seconds;

    var timeNow = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if ( (el.timeNotation == '12h') && (el.am_pm == true) ) {
     timeNow += am_pm_text;
    }

    return timeNow;
  };

  // plugin defaults
  $.fn.jclock.defaults = {
    timeNotation: '24h',
    am_pm: false,
    utc: false,
    fontFamily: '',
    fontSize: '',
    foreground: '',
    background: '',
    utc_offset: 0
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Got it fixed but just the last issue is that the jquery doesnt want to display the clock after I've overwritten the file with your jquery script above.

Comment: I only overwritten the file with your script above and created the gettime.php which works and provides the required time from server. Just it doesnt want to show it on website .. dont know why. UPDATE: Oh, okay. thanks a lot.

Comment: I still cant display it. UPDATE: Oh, you never edited the jquery function. Only the php echo time one. Let me know once it's fixed, so I can try.
Much appreciated, Crush.

Comment: @nLal Should be fixed now.

Comment: @nLal What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I believe it's jQuery 1.2.2 Also, it's not from the version. It worked before but since we've edited it shows this.

Comment: @nLal also, please check that your php script is returning a number.

Comment: @nLal that's really old version...can you try a newer version of jQuery?

Comment: Yes, it's returning a number. 1369753799
One more  thing .. can I change the url in the jquery to a specific location like: hostname.com/gettime.php ?

Comment: @nLal yeah that's no problem. It seems there is an issue with the jQuery version you are using, and the fix I gave. Do you have the ability to use a newer version of jQuery?

Comment: Yeah, I want to use the older version for my other stuff.
Is there a way to use the newer version for this clock jquery only ?

Comment: @nLal Okay, try that. Works for 1.2.3 (oldest version I could find).

Comment: Finally it works. It's much appreciated. Will mark as accepted this answer. I really appreciate your help. Just can you answer me to make sure that there aren't any security wholes in the script right?

Comment: Absolutely no security holes. Also, one last edit that seems to work in newer versions as well as the old versions (give it a try please).

Comment: even gettime.php can be left like that somewhere in my root folder ?

Comment: Yeah, because all it does is output the server time. There is no entry point for an attacker to abuse it as it accepts to input.

Comment: I've accepted the question. I'm sorry that I cant vote up the answer or any of your comments but it says that I need at least 15 reputation. I really appreciate your help once again, Crush. Thank you.

Comment: Also, won't this overload the website since gettime.php is requested in every page load or I'm wrong and it wont cause troubles ?

Comment: @nLal if calling GetTime.php everytime the page is loaded overloads your web server, you have serious issues. No, it shouldn't overload the web server...

Answer (score 0):

`var now = new Date();` creates a date timestamp based on the client's system. I guess this gets called client side?

Comment: Yep. He'll need to make some type of AJAX call to the server to get the servers time in milliseconds, then feed that to `var now = new Date(milliseconds);`

Comment: So, how I should change this line `var now = new Date();` ?

Comment: Please note that the server time may not be exact due to the HTTP request.

Comment: Yeah, a few seconds more or less aren't a problem. I just dont know how exactly to edit my current script, so It will grab the server time .. will be much appreciated if someone can help me out and upload the edited script on pastebin.com

Comment: write a php script with $time = time(); and an jQuery ajax function which gets the value. var now = $.ajax({ settings }); maybe this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804327/jquery-ajax-call-from-javascript-to-php

Comment: @Alex `echo $time;` you mean.

Comment: @crush how the php value is output is another question, i just wanted to make sure to use time() (in my example I am just saving the stamp in the variable $time, not printing or echoing at all ;) )

Comment: Alright. I've got another idea ... how to make it so that the time offset will work correctly instead of getting the time from server side machine ? Now when I set time offeset to +3 for example it displays the time from the user that is browsing thr website. so there still must be a way to display the clock for time zone +3 gmt for example

Answer (score 0):

jQuery runs clientside (on the PC you use to browse to the website) and therefore it will use the client's time. If you want to use the time of the server you need to modified your script and pass the current server time to your script (and use this time instead of `new Date()`).

Comment: I've got it but I'm really unsure how exactly to do it, so I won't mess up something. So which lines in my script I should change or if it's possible to change them and upload on pastebin.com
Will be really grateful.